# React controlled checkbox input. Use "value" or "checked" property?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, react-hooks

See the snippet below:

What is the difference between using `value` or `checked` attribute when controlling a checkbox input with React?

Which one should I use?

```js
function App() {

  const [inputState, setInputState] = React.useState(false);

  function onChange(event) {
    const inputValue = event.target.checked;
    setInputState(inputValue);
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        Using value
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={inputState}      // USES value
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Using checked
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={onChange}
          checked={inputState}      // USES checked
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
input {
  transform: scale(1.5) translateX(10px);
}

div {
  margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id ="root"/>
```

Comment: `value`-based checkbox is not *controlled* as toggling state (e.g. with another checkbox) does not affect its status

Comment: Without a clear understanding of what you will do with those checkboxes next, you will get vague opinions, rather than to-the-point answer.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I need to control its state and read `true` or `false` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight difference between value and checked attribute on Checkbox

**checked   Boolean;** if present, the checkbox is toggled on by default

**value**   The string to use as the value of the checkbox when submitting the form, if the checkbox is currently toggled on

Checked attribute is defined to specify whether the checkbox is checked or not whereas value is used to assign a value which is used when the checkbox is checked

The default value of a checkbox when checked is `on`

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) cover this in quite detail

Answer (score 0):

Officially, you should be using the `checked` property if you are working with `input` elements that are of type `checkbox`. This is stated on the official [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute). From there, on your `App` component, you can simply toggle the checkbox state by setting the state to `true` or `false`.

That being said, using the `value` props/attribute works too. However, personally, I would advise against doing so, even though it may work.